# Whats the difference between ContentControl.Template and ContentControl.ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, contentcontrol

What's the difference between ContentControl.Template and ContentControl.ContentTemplate?
And when do I use which?

For example I could write in a xaml file for WPF:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Label Content="This is from the Template"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Template>
</ContentControl>
```

*Notice the ContentControl.**Template** Tag*

or I could write this:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="This is From the ContentTemplate"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

*Notice the ContentControl.**ContentTemplate** Tag*

The output looks the same and in the first case I use a ControlTemplate and in the other a DataTemplate. However, how should I deceide if I have to use .Template or .ContentTemplate? And what implications does this have (e. g. on DataBinding, Property Inheritance, ...).

Answer (score 29):

[Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) property defines the appearence of a Control itself and [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) defines the template of the `Content` area of a Control. Interesting point from MSDN:

> If a Control does not have a ControlTemplate, the Control will not
>   appear in your application.

This becomes more clear when we take a look at the data types of both properties:

- [Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) property type is [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx)
- [ContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) property type is [DataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx) and you can switch it in runtime using [ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx)